# Compare 2 dictionary by value and drop some k, v python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionary :

```
First = {'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 0.0, 'D': 0.0, 'E': 0.0, 'F': 0.0, 'G': 0.0, 'H': 0.0, 'I': 0.0, 'J': 0.0, 'K': 0.47, 'L': 0.0, 'M': 0.0, 'N': 0.0, 'O': 0.0, 'P': 0.0, 'Q': 0.0, 'R': 0.0, 'S': 0.41, 'T': 0.0}
```

and

```
Second = {'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 0.0, 'D': 0.0, 'E': 0.0, 'F': 0.0, 'G': 0.0, 'H': 0.0, 'I': 0.18, 'J': 0.0, 'K': 1.0, 'L': 0.0, 'M': 0.0, 'N': 0.0, 'O': 0.0, 'P': 0.0, 'Q': 0.0, 'R': 0.0, 'S': 0.32, 'T': 0.0}
```

I woud like to drop certain values in second dict with conditions :

1 - if value in second dict is  <  to value un first dict, drop the (k,v) to the second dict

2 - if value in second dict == 0.0 then drop the (k,v) to the second dict

Fanaly, we have result :

```
Second = {'I': 0.18,'K': 1.0, 'S': 0.32}
```

Here is my code :

```
for key, value in dict(Second).items():
    for key, value in dict(First).items():
        if Second[value] == First[value] :
            del Second[key] 
        elif First[value]> Second[value]:
            del Second[key]

Second
```

But dont work :

```
KeyError: 0.0
```

Can someone help me !

Comment: The keys are strings, not numbers. So `Second[value]` etc. make no sense.

Comment: What is `Nan_Admin`?

Comment: For key S value, `0.32` is less than `0.4` still it is there in your final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't lookup a value as a key to a dictionary.  Also, your 2nd loop is causing you to loop through the Second dictionary after you've already cleared all the elements that you want to clear.

You're looking for something more like:

```
for key, value in dict(Second).items():
    if Second[key] == First[key] :
        del Second[key] 
    elif First[key]> Second[key]:
        del Second[key]
```

or even better

```
for key, value in Second.items():
    if Second[key] <= First[key]:
        del Second[key]
```

though your second condition, specifies it should be something more like:

```
for key, value in Second.items():
    if Second[key] < First[key] or Second[key] == 0.0:
        del Second[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the first dict, since it won't be the one changing, and based on your conditions filter stuff out

```
for k,v in First.iteritems():
    if Second[k] < v or Second[k] == 0.0:
        del Second[k]
```

output:

```
{'I': 0.18, 'K': 1.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mistakenly using the item value rather than the key in an attempt to access the value. Also, you will run into problems if you attempt to mutate the dict while iterating over it. Instead, you could use dict comprehension.

For example:

```
d1 = {'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 0.0, 'D': 0.0, 'E': 0.0, 'F': 0.0, 'G': 0.0, 'H': 0.0, 'I': 0.0, 'J': 0.0, 'K': 0.47, 'L': 0.0, 'M': 0.0, 'N': 0.0, 'O': 0.0, 'P': 0.0, 'Q': 0.0, 'R': 0.0, 'S': 0.41, 'T': 0.0}
d2 = {'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 0.0, 'D': 0.0, 'E': 0.0, 'F': 0.0, 'G': 0.0, 'H': 0.0, 'I': 0.18, 'J': 0.0, 'K': 1.0, 'L': 0.0, 'M': 0.0, 'N': 0.0, 'O': 0.0, 'P': 0.0, 'Q': 0.0, 'R': 0.0, 'S': 0.32, 'T': 0.0}

d2 = {k: v for k, v in d2.items() if v != 0 and v != d1[k]}
print(d2)
# {'I': 0.18, 'K': 1.0, 'S': 0.32}
```